Why did my Olympus AZ-330 Superzoom not focus and wash out my pictures?
I am new to film photography and I took these pictures in bright lighting, without flash (I read about it, now I know I should have used flash). I used Kodak Gold 200 in these pictures, and my photos turned out completely bad. I did get a couple of nice ones, but I have no idea what my mistake is, or if my camera is just broken, as I did get it second-hand. Can someone please help me? Example photos:






Looks about in focus to me. The camera could be using the wrong film sensitivity because it can't read the DX sensitivity coding on the film canister. Maybe clean the relevant contacts. Also from experience (had that camera a long time ago), it eats a box of batteries for breakfast so how good are the batteries?

I'm not familiar with the camera. Do you have exposure compensation set? Which metering mode are you in? How is exposure (aperture/shutter speed) set on this camera? Does it only have scene-specific exposure modes? (e.g. sport, night, portrait, landscape)

By the way, you should not be using flash in bright daylight. It will either have no effect, or could even have a counterproductive effect. Flash only needs to be used when the scene is dark, to add light to the scene. (Worth remembering that the power of camera flash diminishes quickly with distance, and is useless over long distances in any case.)

These photos look to be suffering from camera shake to me. They also look overexposed - which would suggest a shutter speed so long that it's allowing too much light into the film, as well as allowing for camera movement during exposure. This is also reflected in the photo of the waterfall, where the water has been captured with a milky effect from a long exposure.
